# Calling LoadingIndicator as required

Tags: react-admin

I would like to call the LoadingIndicator or a busy indicator during a process so that the user cannot navigate away while the process is in progress.

I cannot find anything in the documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In react-admin, the loading indicator reacts to custom Redux actions. If you want to start it, you can dispatch them manyally:

```js
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchStart, fetchEnd } from 'react-admin'; 

const MyComponent = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();
   const startLoader = () => {
      dispatch(fetchStart());
   }

   const endLoader = () => {
      dispatch(fetchEnd());
   }

   return (/* ...*/);
}
```

However, this doesn't block user navigation. If you want to block users, you should use [a material-ui Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/).